# Local repository use

Tags: maven-2, maven, build

While building Maven projects (Spring and jbpm 4.4 to be specific),
I see that the libraries that I already have in Maven local repository, gets downloaded again or the console log suggests so.

Say my local repo already have the commons-collection3.1 in my library, is it necessary to download from the maven repository?

Is there a setting that can let maven know to look in the local repo first?

Thanks,
Ayusman

Comment: Are the dependencies downloaded are snapshots? If so, that makes sense. else, sometimes, Maven checks for updates of the existing jars. But it will not download any dep if the latest version is present in the local repo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have the updatePolicy for SNAPSHOT repository set to always in your settings.xml. See this guide to [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-settings/settings.html).

Answer (score 5):

Maven will look in the local repository first by default.

> Downloading in Maven is triggered by a project declaring a dependency that is not present in the local repository.

- http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html